# How to calculate this mathematical expression in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, expression

I wanted to calculate this mathematical expression in python3:

```
Xi = (70 + 1344736401384689745317259585614247891453883777111/315)% 115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342422259061068512044369
```

But I'm getting this wrong result: 4.2690044488402846e+45 . Is there something wrong in the expression? how can I fix it to give me the right result?

Comment: It looks like the values you have entered are being converted to floating point numbers so you get a floating point result. I think you want to ensure that you're working with integers instead of floats, and you'll want multiple-word integers instead of single-word integers also. I don't remember how to work with multi-word integers in Python, maybe that's something to search for.

Comment: Isn't `4.2690044488402846e+45` the right answer..

Comment: @ggorlen I'm using python3

Comment: The / means the division result will be a floating point, try //? What is the answer you’re hoping for?

Comment: @ggorlen I edited the question , for mod I used %

Comment: @Moosefeather no it's not

Comment: @ChaiMa `70 + 1344736401384689745317259585614247891453883777111 // 315 == 4.2690044488402846e+45` and you're doing mod a much larger number which means the answer is still `4.2690044488402846e+45`. What am I missing.

Comment: If you need more precision, you can also use the `mpmath` package which provides arbitrary precision arithmetic. Specifically, look at the `mpf` class.

Comment: There is no `mod` operator in Python, unless you use some library and your code example is incomplete. Please provide a complete and reproducible example, and explain why do you think that the result is incorrect.

Comment: Please read [ask]. When you assert that something is "the wrong answer", please also include the answer you believe to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confused because it is showing scientific notation? `'{}'.format()` should help in that case.

```
Xi = (70 + 1344736401384689745317259585614247891453883777111/315)% 115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342422259061068512044369
print('{0:f}'.format(Xi))
```